# Nested objects with unique-index

Tags: spring, mongodb

I just moved from mongo 2.0.6 do 3.2 and noticed that the unique-index is now used for nested objects too.
Is there a way to tell mongo to prevent unique-index for nested objects?

I declare the index for the nested-object like `@Indexed(unique = true)`

Spring version: 4.2.5.RELEASE

Spring-data-mongodb version: 1.8.4.RELEASE

Mongo-driver version: mongo-java-driver 3.2.2

My Code:

```
package jobs;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
@Document(collection = "jobs")
public class Job {

private String title;
private CityInfo cityInfo;

// getter/setter
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public CityInfo getCityInfo() {
    return cityInfo;
}

public void setCityInfo(CityInfo cityInfo) {
    this.cityInfo = cityInfo;
}
}

package jobs;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.Indexed;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
@Document(collection = "city_infos")
public class CityInfo {

@Indexed(unique = true)
private String cityName;

// getter/setter
public String getCityName() {
    return cityName;
}

public void setCityName(String cityName) {
    this.cityName = cityName;
}
}


package jobs;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;
public class JobMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MongoOperations mongo = MongoPoolingUtils.getCentralTemplate();
    CityInfo cityInfo = new CityInfo();
    cityInfo.setCityName("Berlin");
    Job job1 = new Job();
    job1.setTitle("java coder");
    job1.setCityInfo(cityInfo);
    Job job2 = new Job();
    job2.setTitle("php coder");
    job2.setCityInfo(cityInfo);
    mongo.save(job1);
    mongo.save(job2);
}
}
```

Only 1 job is saved to the database.

Comment: The mongo-java-driver is 3.2.2

Comment: Then don't declare the index on the nested class. The only reason it creates is because you actually declared it with the annotation. Don't.

Comment: Hi Blakes,Thank you for your reply. I created a class "Job" that holds a class "CityInfo". The CityInfo has a unique key cityName.
The CityInfo is also stored in a separated database where the cityName unique-index is needed.
In my case using CityInfo as a nested object the unique-index makes it unpossible to save 2 jobs in the same city. I think there is a trick to tell mongodb to oppress the unique-index for nested-objects.  Maybe it is not documented here or i am search at the wrong place.

Comment: Show your code and actual document structure and what you want to do. You almost certain **do not want** an "unique" index on array elements, unless it is on a "truly unique" identifier applied "collection wide". Maintaining "unique" items within an array "per document" is **not** a task for indexes. You use array operations in updates to ensure uniqueness there instead.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. There is an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36176608/edit) link and function that allows you to add these details nicely and cleanly in your "question" and not within very unreadable "comments".